# What is the nodejs equivalent of pipe()?

Tags: node.js

I need to spawn a child process and pass as argument a file descriptor where the child will write progress data. My nodejs app would then read this progress data and do something with it.

In linux, I would use the `pipe()` function to create a pair of connected file descriptors. I would pass the write side FD to the child, and read from the read side in the parent. Also I'd close the read FD in the parent and the write FD in the child after fork().

I don't want to use the 3 standard descriptors in stdio for the progress data, but a separate file descriptor.

I don't want to use a named pipe or a Unix socket.

What is the node.js equivalent of `pipe()`?

### My research (dead ends)

- There is an native npm library `node-pipe2` which does exactly what I need, but it has no users (1 download/week), and supports only OSX and Linux, but not Windows. Lack of popularity means it may have yet undiscovered bugs that might bite me.
- Seems I need a `FileHandle` which is created by `fsPromises.open()`, but open requires a filename.
- The node source implements a class `PipeWrap` in `src/pipe_wrap.cc` which is appears to implement the fsPromises, but it does not call `uv_pipe()` which is the function that would create the pair of connected descriptors. It looks like this feature is not implemented, at least not using `fsPromises`
- the `pipeline` in `stream` connects stdio between child processes, not arbitrary pipes
- `Duplex` in `stream` has nothing to do with file descriptors, but implements a pipe between javascript functions.
- The npm native library `ffi-napi` would allow me to call libc's `pipe()` function, but I'd still have to implement the OSX and Windows equivalents.
- A ChatGPT search of this question recommends Unix Sockets.

### My current solution

Until I find a built-in solution, I will use `node-pipe2`, and deal with the limitations of no-Windows support. It is also the first native library I use in my project, which needs to run on x64 as well as arm64. I can't test on arm64 at the moment, so that could be a new source of unexpected failures.

Surely I'm not the first person in the world to want IPC using pipes other than stdio. Please help! Any hints/comments would be useful.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for NodeJS’ `child_process.fork()` and then relying on `process.send()` to communicate between the parent and child processes.

Comment: @jorgenkg, thank you for your response, it gets me right on track. Based on your pointers I found [this ipc example gist](https://gist.github.com/zeteticl/1e40587ff6f959483a38db8c09eddb88) seems like a complete example. I learnt that the child will receive the `NODE_CHANNEL_FD` env variable, and the serialization can be set to "Advanced" in the fork() call, to enable arbitrary data type over the IPC. I'd be happy to accept a complete answer, and thank you very much for the accurate pointers.